In a russian roulette what if two bullets are randomly put in two consecutive positions?
I am solving problem in the book "A practical guide for quantitative finance interviews". There I had a question on Russian Roulette Series:
You are playing a game of Russian Roulette. If instead of one bullet, two bullets are randomly put in two consecutive positions, in the chamber. Your opponent played the first and he was alive after the first trigger pull. You don't spin the barrel. What is the probability that you loose in this round?
I looked at the solution for the above question and that for when there are bullets  with everything else the same, and can't tell why there would be a difference in survival given that you don't spin in both cases.
My issue is, I figured out that the chance of survival if I don't spin would be $3/5$(Please tell me what is a fundamental mistake here!). I am confused when I spin after the first shoot. Will my chance of survival would be $4/6$? I thought that I need to consider two consecutive bullets as a single element and the chance of survival would be $4/5$.
Then I figured out one way of thinking that to put 2 consecutive random bullets I need to choose one place randomly out of $6$ and I will put another bullet next to that position. Hence, $6C1=6$ ways. Now to survive, I can't choose a place that I am going to shoot, moreover the place before that as well. Hence total $4C1=4$ ways, which will give the probability as $4/6=2/3$.
In the book they said "If you spin the barrel, each position has an equal probability of being chosen, and you chance of survival is only $2/3$." What is way the way of thinking in this statement? I thought we can think equally probable when 2 bullets are randomly distributed but we have a condition of being consecutive here. I want to invite you on how you see this problem and answer.

What does the solution for the above question say?

To add to the above comment: what does the solution say about the case where the chamber is not spun?

It would be $3/4$ for survival, which is reasonable as we have 3 positions w/o bullet. You can think if we have 1,2 with bullet and person 1 survived.

How many positions are there?

If you don't spin then there is only one bullet that can kill you: the bullet that comes after an empty chamber. The other bullet can't kill you because it comes after the first bullet, and you know the first player didn't get the chamber with the first bullet.

For the spinning case, why do you think it makes a difference that the bullets are consecutive? The empty chambers also are consecutive.

@DavidK Ha!.  Consider this.  Take the consecutive chambers as a single unit and the consecutive bullets as a single unit.  Probability of survival is $\frac 12$.  Take the second and third chamber as a single unit but the other two as separate elements. And the bullets as separate units, survival is $\frac 35$.  Take one bullet and the four empty chambers as one and the other bullet as the other.  Then your chance of death is $\frac 12+\frac 12\frac 15=\frac 35$

Indeed if you spin it's irrelevant where the two bullets are located as by spinning you pick one random position, so the probability of picking the spot where the first bullet is, the second, or any of the four remaining empty chambers is the same.
So 4/6 is the answer.
Instead if you don't spin, then you will survive unless the two bullets (X) are exactly placed after your empty chamber (O):
XXOOO -> X
OXXOO -> O
OOXXO -> O
OOOXX -> O
so the probability of survival is 3/4.

You said:

I figured out that the chance of survival if I don't spin would be 3/5(Please tell me what is a fundamental mistake here!)

I can't tell you what your fundamental mistake is because you didn't explain why you thought it was $\frac35$.
But I can explain why it is $\frac34$.
Let's call the chambers with bullets $A,B$ and the chambers without $C,D,E,F$.
The other player is still alive, so he didn't get $A$ or $B$. He must have had $C,D,E,$ or $F$.  In these cases you have $D,E,F,$ or $A$ respectively.
If you have $D,E,$  or $F$, you survive. If you have $A$ you don't. So your chance to survive is $\frac34$.


I thought that I need to consider two consecutive bullets as a single element and the chance of survival would be 4/5.

If you combine the two bullets to be a single chamber, then it is twice as fat and twice as likely to occur.
If you label the empty chambers as $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ and the bullet as $b$ then the probabilities are $P(e_1)=P(e_2)=P(e_3)=P(e_4) = p$ and $P(b) = 2P(e_1) = 2P(e_2) =2P(e_3)=2P(e_4)$.  And as $P(e_1) + P(e_2) + P(e_3) + P(e_4) + P(b)$ must equal $1$ we get.....
$1 = P(e_1) + P(e_2) + P(e_3) + P(e_4) + P(b)=p + p + p + p +2p = 6p$ so $p=\frac 16$ and the probability of survival is $4\times p = \frac 23$.
It's easier to just consider the two bullets as two cases.  And logistically, $4$ safe chambers, $2$ unsafe chambers out of $6$ total has to be $\frac 46$.
Considering two cases as one can not warp space and time to make them have the physical properties as one when they aren't.
=====
Don't spin, two consecutive bullets:  There are four empty chambers.  One of them is before a bullet and the other three are not before a bullet. If the previous player gets the chamber before a bullet you will absolutely die.  If the previous player got one of the three chambers not immediately before a bullet you will live.  The probability the previous player didn't get the chamber immediately before a bullet is $\frac 34$ so your chance of survival is $\frac 34$.
Don't spin, two non-consecutive bullets: There are four empty chamber. Two of them are immediately before a bullet and two of them are not.  The previous player is equally likely to have gotten a chamber immediately before a bullet as not.  Your probability of survival is one half.
Spin:  Spinning starts afresh and you probability is exactly the same as though the previous player had never played.  No matter how you place the bullets $4$ out of $6$ of the chambers are empty and your probability of survival is $\frac 46=\frac 23$.
....
A more interesting question I think would be to say you are told two bullets are placed at random but you don't know how.  The player shoots and survives.  What is your probability of surviving?

 Answer:  Suppose the first bullet is put in a first chamber.  There are $5$ remaining chambers for the second bullet.  $2$ of the chambers are next to the bullet.  So the probability of the bullets being consecutive is $\frac 25$ and the probability they are not is $\frac 35$.  So the probability of survival is $\frac 25 \times \frac 34 + \frac 35\times \frac 12= \frac 35$.

Also interesting is if there are three bullets.  If all three bullets are consecutive your probability of surviving is $\frac 23$.  (why?).  If two are consecutive and the other separate your probability of survival is $\frac 13$.  (why?). ...  But if no bullets are consecutive then the probability that you will die is $100\%$!
